# Reg expression seems like it should be greedy, but acting non-greedy

Tags: python, regex

I'm surprised by this:

```
dfnew = df.rename(columns=lambda x: re.sub('.*(\d?\d\.\d).*','ass \\1', x ))
```

If the column is called "Assignment 3.2" it is renamed to "ass 3.2" (good)
But, if the column is called "Assignment 12.2" it is renamed to "ass 2.2" (not good)

I thought I had it set up just right. Can you see what I am missing?

Comment: `.*` is greedy, and it goes first.

Comment: gotcha! How do I make it non-greedy?

Comment: https://regexr.com/3hdfa

Comment: `.*?` is the way

Comment: Can it happen that you have `2.2.2.2.22`

Comment: I think you actually want: `r'.*\b(\d+\.\d+)\b.*'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dfnew = df.rename(columns=lambda x: re.sub('.* (\d+\.\d).*','ass \\1', x ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. Here's the solution:

```
dfnew = df.rename(columns=lambda x: re.sub('.*?(\d?\d\.\d).*','ass \\1', x ))
```